# Maximum principle to get $C^0$ estimates in terms of $L^1$ norms

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations, poissons-equation

I'm reading this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7366 and trying to prove Corollary 4.6.

The result essentially says the following. Let $B_r \subseteq \mathbb R^4$ be the ball of radius $r$ with the standard metric. Suppose $\phi: B_1 \to \mathbb R$, ($\phi$ smooth and bounded) satisfies the equation
$$
\Delta |\phi|^2 = Q(\phi, \phi) + P(\phi).
$$
Here $Q(\phi, \phi)$ is some quadratic function where we have a bound
$$
|Q(\phi, \phi)| \leq C|\phi|^2
$$
for some $C$, and $P(\phi) \geq 0$. With this setup they claim that there is a constant $D$, independent of $\phi$, such that
$$
\sup_{x \in B_{1 - \varepsilon}}|\phi|^2 \leq D\int_{B_1} |\phi|^2.
$$

Apparently this is just an application of the maximum principle. By this I think that the proof should go in the following way. Let $u$ be a solution to Poisson's equation

$$
\Delta u = Q(\phi, \phi), \quad u|_{\partial B_1} = |\phi|^2.
$$

Then the maximum principle applied to $|\phi|^2 - u$ gives that $|\phi|^2 \leq u$. Now I think there should be some facts about solutions to Poisson's equation that give estimates of the form

$$
\sup_{x \in B_{1 - \varepsilon}} u \leq A\|\Delta u\|_{L^1(B)}
$$

from which the result would follow, but I'm unsure of how to prove such an estimate.

Comment: At least your last inequality is false in general. Just take $u(x) = 1/|x|$, then $\Delta u = -\mathrm{div}(x/|x|^3) = -1/|x|^3$ is integrable on $B_1\subset \Bbb R^4$ but $u$ is of course not bounded.

Comment: @LL3.14 True, thanks, although there are some restrictions on $u$ coming from the assumptions on $Q$ and $\phi$. So what I've written doesn't hold in general but may hold in this situation